# Can you change color of IntelliJ Dart closing comments?

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, dart

I know you can completely turn off Dart closing comments, but is there any way to just change the color of them? I'd like to keep them but make them less intrusive by making them a lighter shade of grey.

I also know you can change the color of line comments in general, but that also affects comments that I add myself. I want to be able to change the color of *just* the closing comments that are automatically added to Dart code in IntelliJ.

Comment: Not possible yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31828

Answer (score 0):

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "dart.closingLabels": "#323232"
},
```

add in settings.json

Comment: this is for VS Code. the question is not about VS Code.